# Include NuGet packages in TeamCity

Tags: c#, windows-services, teamcity, nuget, .net-4.5

I recently started using NuGet to manage external packages. For now I have only needed it for NLog. 
Everything works fine when I Build the project in VS 2012. However, I am trying out TeamCity as a CI server (I'm fairly new to CI) and it is giving me the following error:

```
[Csc] SomeNamespace\SomeClass.cs(10, 7): error CS0246: 
The type or namespace name 'NLog' could not be found 
(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

(this error is repeated throughout where ever I use NLog)

Now I did not include the 'packages/' folder in SVN, since I thought it was good practice not to include binaries and let MSBuild in TeamCity download these on its own. However it's clearly not doing that. I DO include the 'packages.xml' file in SVN.
What can I check to see what is going wrong?

**Update**
Thanks to @DavidBrabant I was nudged in the right direction. However, I now get the following error in TeamCity:

```
Package restore is disabled by default. To give consent, open the Visual Studio Options dialog, 
click on Package Manager node and check 'Allow NuGet to download missing packages during build.'
```

However I'm not in Visual Studio but TeamCity, so I do not know how to set 'consent' to true! I tried to set RestorePackages to 'true' in the NuGet.targets file:

```
<RestorePackages Condition="  '$(RestorePackages)' == '' ">true</RestorePackages>
```

but this didn't work.

**Update 2**
To make it work I also set the following property NuGet.targets:

```
<RequireRestoreConsent Condition=" '$(RequireRestoreConsent)' != 'true' ">false</RequireRestoreConsent>
```

This made the build run succesfully!

Comment: can you connect to Nuget repository from CI machine (can you ping it)?

Comment: Did you enable package restoration?

Comment: Actually it is best practice to have everything you need to build your project in repository.

Comment: Mate, may be I am really stupid but it takes a lot of time for me to understod that last string must look like `<RequireRestoreConsent Condition=" '$(RequireRestoreConsent)' != 'true' ">false</RequireRestoreConsent>` I think it makes sense to specify the right string, not the inital version of it.

Comment: Thanks Seekeer, I changed it accordingly!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The enable package restore feature built into NuGet allows you to very easily set up the pre-build part of the workflow. To do so, right-click the solution node in Visual Studio’s Solution Explorer, and click the Enable NuGet Package Restore option. Note that you need to have the NuGet Visual Studio Extension installed on your system. If you do, and you still don’t see this menu item appear, you either already enabled this option, or you have a folder named .nuget in your solution directory.

After having set that option, you can now delete all sub-folders of your package installation directory, by default $(SolutionDir)\packages, except for the repositories.config file, and your solution should still compile properly. During compilation, you should see NuGet installation traces in the Visual Studio output window, and you should see the required NuGet packages reappear in the package installation directory as well.

Also see [Using Nuget without committing packages](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages).

Comment: This has now been superseded with automatic package restore integrated into MSBuild http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/migrating-to-automatic-package-restore and http://www.xavierdecoster.com/migrate-away-from-msbuild-based-nuget-package-restore

Answer (score 12):

Just to reiterate on update 2.  If you stumbled here looking for a quick fix to TeamCity not downloading NuGet packages, try changing this line

```
<RequireRestoreConsent Condition=" '$(RequireRestoreConsent)' != 'false' ">true</RequireRestoreConsent>
```

to this line

```
<RequireRestoreConsent Condition=" '$(RequireRestoreConsent)' != 'true' ">false</RequireRestoreConsent>
```

in your `NuGet.targets` file and it should work.

Comment: I don't have a nuget.target. It's not supposed to be there for package restore.

Answer (score 8):

In TeamCity v8 I was able to solve the "restore package" error using an environment variable in TC.

See:

http://johanleino.wordpress.com/2013/03/19/using-teamcity-for-asp-net-development-part-2/

and

http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Configuring+Build+Parameters#ConfiguringBuildParameters-SystemPropertiesandEnvironmentVariables

Setting `env.EnableNuGetPackageRestore` to "true" as an environment variable at the project level will fix the problem for all build configurations.  Feels a little bit better doing this than editing the NuGet.targets file imho.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this post: http://johanleino.wordpress.com/2013/06/17/making-use-of-teamcitys-nuget-capabilities-part-2/

As described there I added first build step "NuGet Installer", made some coinfiguration and now packages are automatically restored.

Comment: I tried the environment variable fix above by Nate Rickard, but it didn't work. The fix here by @Bounz worked perfectly for me.

Comment: I agree. Similar info here: http://www.michael-whelan.net/restoring-nuget-packages-in-teamcity/